# Use GetTempFileName function to generate random file name on C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to use the [GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx) function to generate a random file name but without creating the file itself when the function gets called. I want to use that function to use the name itself (and without the extension) so later I can create a folder with that particular name. Since there is no similar function that creates a folder, I just want to get the string that GetTempFileName creates to later on create a folder.

```
LPTSTR wzTemp = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
GetTempFileName(strTemp, 0, 0, wzTemp);

CString tempFolder;
tempFolder = wzTemp;
```

This is my attempt but right after GetTempFileName the file gets created.

Any idea how can I tweak this?

Comment: A better option would be to use a GUID instead of a randomly generated filename (the `GetTempFileName()` documentation even says so). See `CoCreateGuid()` and `StringFromGUID2()`, or `UuidCreate()` and `UuidToString()`.

Comment: I would like to avoid creating a super long guid. Would that be possible?

Comment: You want to create a random folder and not a file, so I suggest you duplicate the algorithm that `GetTempFileName()` uses: "*If uUnique is zero, the function attempts to form a unique file name using the current system time. If the file already exists, the number is increased by one and the functions tests if this file already exists. This continues until a unique filename is found*". You can accomplish those tasks using `CreateDirectory()` and `FindFirstFile()`, for instance.

Comment: Or better, don't even bother using random numbers, simply format the current system time down to milliseconds as a human-readable string.  If you find a folder that already exists, just wait a few milliseconds and try again

Comment: You don't want to start with GetTempFileName and tweak it. 
 GetTempFileName creates the file to guarantee that there's no race condition between when it determines certain name is available until it "claims" that name.  You can emulate that logic to create a directory instead of a file.

Comment: Marked your answers with a +1 since these are totally valid and also worked well for me. Thanks!

Comment: What about if you want to create a random file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the file, remove the extension from the generated name, then create the folder.

Comment: That creates a TOCTOU race. `GetTempFileName` is used to create a file. If you need to create a folder, don't use it.

Answer (score 5):

[GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991.aspx) is responsible for creating a file. If you want to create a unique directory instead, you have to write your own implementation. Using `GetTempFileName`, then deleting the file, and creating a directory with the same name in its place is doomed to fail, due to a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race.

The standard solution to creating unique names is to use string representations of GUIDs. You can call [UuidCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379205(v=vs.85).aspx), followed by [UuidToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379352.aspx) to get one.

If 36 characters is unwieldy in your situation, you would need to write your own implementation, based on a less unique algorithm (like the system time) and a retry strategy.

As an example, here is an implementation, that uses the string representation of the system time, represented as a 64-bit decimal number. That leads to a string representation, that is at most 19 characters wide.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>

std::wstring GetTempDir(std::wstring const& root_dir) {
    while (true) {
        ::SYSTEMTIME st{};
        ::GetSystemTime(&st);

        ::FILETIME ft{};
        if (!::SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft)) {
            auto error_code{ ::GetLastError() };
            throw std::system_error(error_code, std::system_category(),
                                    "SystemTimeToFileTime()");
        }

        ULARGE_INTEGER ft_uli{ ft.dwLowDateTime, ft.dwHighDateTime };
        auto dir_name{ std::to_wstring(ft_uli.QuadPart) };
        auto dir_name_full{ root_dir + dir_name };
        if (::CreateDirectoryW(dir_name_full.c_str(), nullptr)) {
            return dir_name_full;
        }
        else {
            auto error_code{ ::GetLastError() };
            if (error_code != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
                throw std::system_error(error_code, std::system_category(),
                                        "CreateDirectoryW()");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function returns the fully qualified path to the temporary directory it creates, or throws an exception if it cannot. It expects a string to the root directory including a trailing backslash. In case the directory already exists, it keeps trying, until a directory can be created.

Note in particular, that there is no race condition. If the function succeeds, the directory has been created.

It can be called as shown in the following sample:

```
int main() {
    wchar_t path[MAX_PATH + 1]{};
    ::GetTempPathW(_countof(path), path);

    auto temp_dir{ GetTempDir(path) };
    std::wcout << L"Temporary directory created: " << temp_dir << std::endl;
}
```